# How to escape ":" in Oracle dynamic SQL and also have bind variables?

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping

I'm trying to make the following a dynamic SQL, but `:` character is messing up -

```
alter session set events 'sql_trace [sql: asasasaass]';
```

Example:

```
declare
 l_trc_cmd   varchar2(500);
 l_sql_id    varchar2(500) := 'asasasaass';
begin
  l_trc_cmd     := q'# alter session set events 'sql_trace [sql: :L_SQL_ID]' #';
  execute immediate l_trc_cmd using l_sql_id;
end;
/
```

Above fails with:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
```

---

One `:` is required as per syntax of the SQL, and another `:` is for bind variable.

Any ideas on how to fix this other than concatenating the bind value?

--
Edited on April 4th at 5.10pm CST  to add following:

Alter session is not DDL command. Below  is proof.

```
sqlplus+> select * from t2;

         A
----------
         1

1 row selected.

sqlplus+> insert into t2 values(2);

1 row created.

sqlplus+> alter session set tracefile_identifier ="umappsperf1" statistics_level=all;

Session altered.

sqlplus+> alter session set events 'sql_trace wait=true';

Session altered.

sqlplus+> select * from t2;

         A
----------
         2
         1

2 rows selected.

sqlplus+> rollback;

Rollback complete.

sqlplus+> select * from t2;

         A
----------
         1

1 row selected.
```

Comment: What makes you think `ALTER SESSION` is not DDL, and how does running it in SQL*Plus prove it isn't?

Answer (score 4):

For this statement I'd just forget about using a bind variable, e.g.:

```
declare
 l_trc_cmd   varchar2(500);
 l_sql_id    varchar2(500) := 'asasasaass';
begin
  l_trc_cmd := REPLACE(
    q'# alter session set events 'sql_trace [sql: %SQLID%]' #'
    ,'%SQLID%',l_sql_id);
  execute immediate l_trc_cmd;
end;
/
```

Comment: Is it possible at all to use bind variables with DDL?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use bind variables with DDL:

```
SQL> exec execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT :x t FROM DUAL' USING 1;

ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition operations
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

In addition, you don't get this meaningful error message because the `:` characters are already escaped in your statement since they are between quotes (`'`).

Comment: But, alter session is not a DDL. You are correct about the {:} being escaped. I looked up in dbms_sql package spec. Thanks.

Comment: I think all statements that are not DML (insert, update, delete, merge) are considered DDL.

Comment: There are instances where SCL and even DML will refuse bind variables. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25489002/1461424

Comment: @Krumia: your example #4 is somewhat flawed. You can't use bind variables in place of objects, like a column name or a table name. You can always use a bind variables where you could place a constant, like `'A'` or `SYSDATE`. You would never use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYSDATE`, so you can't use a bind variable to replace `SYSDATE` in this expression. This doesn't mean that "DML will refuse bind variables", it just means that you want to do something that is not compatible with bind variables.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat: Yes it is flawed to the point of being stupid. But I've seen people doing it so I included it anyway. Also, you can't always use bind variables even for constants. Consider `CREATE TABLE dummy_table ( dummy_column VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'A' )`. You would not be able to use `dummy_column VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT :def_val)`. You'll get `ORA-01027`.

Comment: @Krumia: but that is DDL, not DML! Exactly like the example in my answer. The whole point of this question!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use bind variables with DDL.  With DML in PL/SQL, you cannot use bind variables either because they are automatically applied when you concatenate values to SQL statements. Each reference to a PL/SQL variable is in fact a bind variable.

http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html

Comment: Correct, bind variable substition is done automatically for you. Minor point though: it is possible in PL/SQL to explicitly use bind variables in DML - e.g. if you use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Answer (score 1):

I was also given following explanation, which correlate with above answers:

> You have to use concatenation (taking
>   care of SQL injection risks, of
>   course).
>
> First,  alter session set events 
>   requires a string literal.  It does
>   not support expressions, where a bind
>   variable could be used.
>
> Second, you try to use a bind variable
>   inside a string literal (embedded in
>   another string literal).  Bind
>   variables are not SQL*Plus
>   substitution variables (&var or
>   &&var).  Substitution variables are
>   applied by SQL*Plus before any parsing
>   and they do not recognize any SQL
>   syntax. They can come up anywhere in
>   any statement. They are applied on the
>   client not in the server.
>
> But host bind variables are SQL syntax
>   elements.  They are  allowed as
>   operands (with a specific SQL data
>   type) in expressions in DML, queries
>   and PL/SQL anonymous blocks. They are
>   not allowed in DDL or session control
>   statements.